# How to find Row number of an object in a List

Tags: linq, list, indexing, row

Hi have the following elements in a List
ListClass[0] = (0,2)
ListClass[1] = (0,3)
ListClass[2] = (0,8)
ListClass[3] = (1,0)
ListClass[4] = (1,1)
ListClass[5] = (2,1)
ListClass[6] = (3,0)
ListClass[7] = (3,1)
ListClass[8] = (3,3)
ListClass[9] = (3,8)

```
public class ListClass
{
    public int rowIndex { get; set; }
    public int columnIndex { get; set; }
    public ListClass()
    {
    }
    public ListClass(int row, int column)
    {
        this.rowIndex = row;
        this.columnIndex = column;
    }
}
```

Please help me with a Linq query which can get the RowNumber of top most result from the List for the following condition.

ListClass.rowIndex >= 0 and ListClass.columnIndex > 4

i,e. result must be **2** according to the given example.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use [`List<T>.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx):

```
int index = list.FindIndex(x => x.rowIndex >= 0 && x.columnIndex > 4);
```

This will return -1 if there's no such value.

Note that conventionally properties are PascalCased, so these should be `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex`.